# Detroy AVPlayer Completely

Tags: ios, avplayer

I used AVPlayer to play youtube video in iOS, i created `VideoViewController` to manage play video.

When VideoViewController pop out NavigationController, i implement

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [self.player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kCurrentItemKey context:MyStreamingMovieViewControllerCurrentItemObservationContext];
    [self.player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kRateKey context:MyStreamingMovieViewControllerRateObservationContext];
    [self removePlayerTimeObserver];
    self.playerLayerView = nil;
    self.playerItem = nil;
    self.player = nil;
}
```

but NetworkAcitivtyIndicator still loading in `Status Bar`, i want stop it. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage activity indicator by yourself? If so, insert this line in your pop method: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO`
Or try to stop player before you set it's reference to nil.

Answer (score 0):

With ARC, objects with a nil value are released at the end of the block or scope in which they are nulled. Although AVPlayer is an object generated by a class cluster (i.e., many different objects), you don't have to release all of them individually,
just the player.

So, this single line will release the player and everything else underneath, including the asset and/or player item:

```
[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
```

If, for some strange reason, you cannot wait until the end of the method to release the player (perhaps it is preceded by a long-running iterator or is retained by a C-inline block variable), encompass the line in an @autorelease pool:

```
@autorelease {
[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.